# Computer setup on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask advice on desk/laptop + *monitor* arrangement.

(My eyes are aging and I find the laptop increasingly hard)

I had seen some funky arrangements at houses in Canada.

Would this question be on topic?
If not any alternate site suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

- Choosing an arrangement would be off-topic as opinion-based.
- Finding/buying furniture would be off-topic.
- Building your own furniture might be on-topic, but likely a better fit would be https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/

The one thing that would be on-topic is if you want to mount things to the building (walls, ceiling, floor) and have specific questions about how to do that properly.

Comment: Thanks a tonne! What I had seen was some funky wall mounted monitor. With suitable non standard chair. And I was wondering what options are available. So my q is more along last para & last point

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but that wouldn't be on topic for Home Improvement.

You could check on [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com), it *might* be on topic there. I can't think of anywhere else.